# query to display information based on month and year

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a table having following information

[image: mysql table]

I want to display information some what like that

[image: Required output]

Actually i am using php to display a google chart for which i need a query which can give me this output. The system should check the month and based on the month it should prepare the report, E.g if its the month of April it should display April for both A and B users as zero. i am using the following query but it

```
SELECT name
      ,month as month
      ,count(*) as no_of_vists 
FROM abc where name = 'A' 
group by month 
order by date(month);
```

Comment: You are fetching two fields with name `name`: SELECT **name**,month as month,**count(name)as name** FROM

Comment: And if you're selecting name and month, then you should also group by name and month

Comment: Check it out now, As for as group by is concern you are right, But here i have used where clause to even get the output of only one user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try as below :

```
select x.name
       ,x.month
       ,count (y.*)
FROM 
   (SELECT b.name
      ,a.month
    FROM (select month from abc) a 
    JOIN (select name from abc) b
        ON (1=1)
    group by 1,2 ) x 
    LEFT JOIN abc y 
    ON (x.month = y.month and x.name = y.name)
group by 1,2
order by 1,2;
```

Output :

```
| name |    month | count |
|------|----------|-------|
|    a | February |     1 |
|    a |  January |     2 |
|    a |    March |     1 |
|    b | February |     0 |
|    b |  January |     1 |
|    b |    March |     0 |
```

Here is the sqlfiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3feb0/24

Comment: Did you see table he want to display? There's not only  'A' name.

Comment: This would give him the idea , not necessarily the answer .

Comment: No still the same output, E.g. Its month of February for user B its not returning Zero. My query seems to be similar to display the sale for the whole year including the months in which no item is sold....

Comment: @Ricky Edited the answer . Please check if this works .

Comment: But two things how can i user where clause to display the output of only NAME 'A' and secondly how can i order it month wise that is January then February and so on